# How to show custom widgets in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I want to implement something like this:
[image]

Show combobox/line edit or checkbox in second column as wish.
Anyone know how to do this ??

Comment: But what is drawn here??)), I did not understand, maybe you want to know how to create a model for qtreeviw?

Comment: You can set an item delegate for a specific column. You can check this link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html . You should create your own ItemDelegate class by inheriting "qstyleditemdelegate".

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-propertybrowser.html, what I need is just a properties editor. @Programmer_ARM